# dynamically apply multiple class names dynamically from json result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Getting multiple class names in single key value from json response. and i need to bind this class names dynamically.

My json result

```
[
{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryValue": "Mobiles",
    "divId": "MobilesId",
    "uiClass": "cat-icons cat-mobile"
}]
```

i am binding value like below

```
<div class="+response[i].uiClass +" />
```

but it is showing like

```
<div class="cat-icons" cat-mobile/>
```

I need the out like below

```
<div class="cat-icons cat-mobile/>
```

please help me!!!

Comment: can you add more like how you are creating <div class="+response[i].uiClass +" />. please try to add more code to explain properly.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: 'myurl',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',  
           // contentType: "application/json;",        
            success: function (response) {   
                for (var i in response)
                 {

                  var template ="<div class="+ response[i].uiclass+">"
                 $('#allItems').a1ppend(template);
                  
                 }
            }
        });

Comment: Are you using jquery or some framework?

Comment: `$.ajax({ url: 'myurl', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', // contentType: "application/json;", success: function (response) { for (var i in response) { var template ="<div class="+ response[i].uiclass+">" $('#allItems').a1ppend(template); } } })`

Comment: `$.ajax({
            url: 'myurl',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', // contentType: "application/json;", 
            success: function (response) { 
              for (var i in response) { 
                var template ="<div class='"+ response[i].uiclass+"'>";
                $('#allItems').append(template); 
              } 
            } 
});`

Comment: User var template ='<div class="'+ response[i].uiClass+'"></div>' ;
 $('#allItems').append(template);

Your code returns <div class=cat-icons cat-mobile></div>. You can see class names are not encloses in single or double quotes so it is neglecting classes after first class name. also your forget to close div also.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you are trying to do, but here is a sample for creating divs using jquery with the exact class name what you need. This one is for a json object same you mentioned in your query. Remaining you can loop it if more than of that are there...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var response = [{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryValue": "Mobiles",
    "divId": "MobilesId",
    "uiClass": "cat-icons cat-mobile"
  }];
  var divs = '<div class="' + response[0].uiClass + '" />';
  $("body").append(divs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

I'm just showing to append the div in the body, you can change it as per your need.

Comment: but it create create the div class like: `<div class="cat-icons" cat-mobile />`  i need the class name like  `<div class="cat-icons cat-mobile' />`

Comment: Wait.. what? I didn't get that.

Comment: It is creating exactly what you asked for... Check it in the developer mode.

Comment: `<div class="cat-icons cat-mobile' />` or `<div class="cat-icons cat-mobile" />`